# Not able to navigate from one type to another in Assembly Explorer from dotPeek

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, dotpeek

I installed ReSharper and dotPeek that comes as an extension for VS 2022. Everything works well, except I cannot navigate to related types using the Assembly Explorer. For example, I can find class A in the Assembly Explorer, but if class A inherits from class B, or it refers to other classes, I am unable to navigate to B or those other related classes from class A. However, separately I can find the class A in the explorer, which would again not allow me to navigate to related classes.

I have reviewed other questions and below is the settings. Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: Some time ago there was a bug that could affect this behavior. Can you try installing the latest ReSharper 2023.3.3 bugfix or 2024.1 EAP7 and check if the behavior is reproduced there?